# perl Shell::GetEnv

Tags: perl, module

I want to source file in perl script, first, I use the below method:

```
system("source env.bash");
```

but I got a error like:

Can't exec "source": No such file or directory at s-test.pl line 10.

I cannot fix the issue, so I use [Shell::GetEnv](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Shell-GetEnv/):

```
use Shell::GetEnv;

$env = Shell::GetEnv->new('bash', 'source env.bash' );

$envs = $env->envs(%opt);
$env->import_envs(%opt);
```

but it seems doesn't work at all, can anyone help me to resolve it? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

`system()` (at least on Unix-like systems) invokes the named command via `/bin/sh`.  Unlike bash, `/bin/sh` doesn't have `source` as a synonym for `.`.

But even if you changed it to `system(". env.bash")`, it wouldn't work.  Presumably `env.bash` sets environment variables (`export FOO=BAR; ...`).  Such settings apply only to the current process.  It would invoke a shell, set the environment variables in that shell, and then have no effect on the invoking (perl) process.

I've never used `Shell::GetEnv` before, but according to the documentation `%opt` is used to pass options to the functions  You haven't shown us what value `%opt` has.  Are you sure you need it?  Perhaps you just want to do:

```
...
$envs = $env->envs();
$env->import_envs();
```

Comment: thanks for answering, it also doesn't work without %opt:(, do you any good idea about source a file in perl script?

Comment: @abner: You can't source a shell script from a Perl script, at least not without the kind of tricks that `Shell::GetEnv` plays.  Your `bash.env` presumably contains commands in bash syntax.  Any chance you can translate `bash.env` into Perl?

Comment: There have some "alias" commands in env.bash, such as "alias prod ='cd $HOME/trunk'", I need to enter $HOME/trunk by "prod" to execute commands, because some reason, I cann't modify bash.env:(

Comment: Aliases definitely aren't going to translate well, and I doubt that `Shell::GetEnv` handles them.  If `bash.env` is reasonably stable, a manual translation to Perl code is probably your best bet.  If not, an automated translation (probably still ad-hoc) will be harder, but will make it easier to keep up with changes.